# can't get gcs to return md5hash and crc32c for uploaded object

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, metadata, md5

I have a python program that uploads a file using google's resumable upload protocol. The upload works fine, but when I try to follow google's suggestion of requesting metadata for the file after upload in order to compare the server-generated md5hash with the hash I generated during upload, my GET request returns an object metadata json blob with no checksum fields.

I've found a reference in gcs docs that indicates that I have to send some special encryption headers in order to get these server-generated checksum fields to be returned in my metadata GET request, but the docs don't say which headers have to be included - and frankly - I'm not using encryption anyway, so I wouldn't know what headers I should send:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get (3rd paragraph)

Interestingly, the google playground (accessible from the link above) allows me to make the object request from their web interface using oauth to access my bucket - I can get this request to return the full object metadata with hash fields. But the playground doesn't indicate the full set of request headers sent (sadly) so I can't even use that to see what I should be sending.

Question: What's the trick to getting google to return the checksum fields when asking for object metadata?

Comment: have you tried `list_blobs()`? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-python

Comment: @MichaelSilverstein - no I don't want to list them - I want to retrieve metadata for a specific one. Also - I'm using the regular json api rather than the google python libraries. My implementation (using python requests) is working fine for upload. Getting metadata should be trivial in comparison.

Comment: Your question is a good example of why questions need to include working source code. If my answer does not solve your problem, edit your question and include a minimum, reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an object's resource representation (metadata), specify the path parameter `alt=json`.

Example:

```
GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket/o/object?alt=json
```

Note: This is the default case. You do need to process the returned JSON data to extract the `md5Hash` key/value.

Google Cloud Object Resource:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects

Comment: Thank you John Hanley - I'm a complete idiot, I admit it. I was trying to pull the md5Hash from response headers. I knew better, but had somehow gotten into the mindset that the value would be in headers. Didn't even think about the data.